# Prove inequality holds

Tags: inequality, induction

Show that:

$\displaystyle 2! \cdot 4! \cdot... \cdot(2n)!>[(n+1)!]^n $ for $n>1$ where $n$ is natural

I tried by induction but I stuck when I have to show that:

$(2n+2)!>(n+2)!(n+2)^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that $\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+2)!}=(n+3)(n+4)...(2n+2)>(n+2)...(n+2)$